# NSGlyph to CGGlyph in Swift (UInt32 to UInt16)

Tags: ios, macos, swift, core-text

How can I go from an NSGlyph to a CGGlyph?

```
        let ctGlyph = glyph as CGGlyph
```

I see that:

```
typealias CGGlyph = CGFontIndex
typealias CGFontIndex = UInt16

typealias NSGlyph = UInt32
```

So how do I do the typecast?

I tried:

```
let ctGlyph = glyph as CGGlyph
```

but it gives me:

> error: 'NSGlyph' is not convertible to 'CGGlyph'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast, but you can use an initializer:

```
let ctGlyph = CGGlyph(glyph)
```